# Invalid bound statement (not found): com.cn.springbootmybatiss.mapper.UserMapper.findAll

Tags: mybatis

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Online lookup, modify the configuration, and try some operations, modify the yml configuration, annotations are not successful

Comment: Do not use images of text rendered to present text content: Copy&paste the text into the post body.